# Rails how to handle error and exceptions in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, twitter

So I'm parsing data from twitter api in rails using the twitter library, and sometimes the response from api might be like this:

```
{
error: "Invalid parameter"
}
```

And the model will raise an exception, right now I'm silently catch it and put the error.message into the log, how do I pass this exception to the controller so I can display it on the view? Thanks.

UPDATE:
The error is likely to happen because I'm allowing my customer to build queries, and they might put advanced queries like `"https://search.twitter.com/search.json?since_id=1&&q=near:NYC%20within:15mi"` which is supported by the twitter webpage but not by it's API. So I want to catch these kinda of error and display a flash message so the user can have some feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you could an `attr_accessor`. Something like `twitter_errors`.

In your model:

```
attr_accessor :twitter_errors

begin
  #your twitter code here
rescue
  self.twitter_errors = "whatever"
end
```

And in your controller, set the flash if `@model.twitter_errors` isn't empty.

Comment: I'm parsing the feed in a class method right now. And wanna display the flash message in the the index page, because there is a update tweet button in the index page. So how I attach this virtual attribute to my class? Thanks!

Comment: sorry, noob alert. I guess `attr_accessor :twitter_errors` is for instance. how do i exactly set up this virtual attribute for the class it self? A class variable like @@somevarible?

Comment: nope, virtual attributes are a smart way to say instance variable for models. For a class, it's a simple instance variable. Simple vocabulary issue there.

Comment: But I got a `NameError: undefined local variable or method `twitter_errors' for #<Object:0x1001dd2a0>` when I use attr_accessor :(

Comment: yes, i just did, and still gets `undefined method `twitter_errors=' for #<Class:0x105d41358>`

Comment: @apneadiving let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2111/discussion-between-randomor-and-apneadiving)

Answer (score 2):

The typical way is to use [`ActiveModel::Errors`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Errors).

ActiveRecord uses this mixin extensively for validations. So in an `ActiveRecord` object you have access to `errors.add(:base, TwitterError.to_s)`. You can use this to set the error when it is caught. And then you should be able to access it via the controller/view using `ar_object.errors`.

(There are already some helpers for displaying errors like this the docs have much more info)

Comment: good idea, I often prefer being more explicit though. Whatever, +1