# How can I handle errors in Rails model, which doesn't have controller and views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model, which is a bridge between my Rails app and API and doesn't have controller and views.

In the following method I get an error, which is an `ActiveResource::ResourceNotFound` error.

```
      def find_order(order_id, cached: false)
        within_temp_session do
          order = find_cached_order(order_id) if cached
          unless order
            order = API::Order.find(order_id)  # here the order can be absent
            cache_order(order.attributes)
          end
          order
        end
      end
```

Ideas that I had were not good from various points of view, like violating MVC concept with calling controller method in model.

**EDIT**: `redirect_to`, `flash[:alert]` do not naturally work, as well as `errors.add error`.

Using [`attr_accessor`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932965/rails-how-to-handle-error-and-exceptions-in-model) helped add errors to model instance, but I do not use model instance anywhere.

How do I notify a user, that an error happened?

Here is the traceback:

```
10 File "/app/app/models/model1.rb", line 24 in block in find_order
11 File "/app/app/models/model1.rb", line 97 in block in within_temp_session
+ 1 non-project frame
13 File "/app/app/models/model1.rb", line 97 in within_temp_session
14 File "/app/app/models/model1.rb", line 21 in find_order
15 File "/app/app/models/model2.rb", line 76 in find_order
16 File "/app/app/models/model3.rb", line 45 in order
17 File "/app/app/models/model3.rb", line 69 in build_call
18 File "/app/app/models/model3.rb", line 50 in shipping_label_form
19 File "/app/app/models/model3.rb", line 55 in create_label
20 File "/app/app/jobs/job.rb", line 8 in block in perform
+ 2 non-project frames
23 File "/app/app/jobs/job.rb", line 7 in perform
```

**EDIT 2:**
User clicks `get shipping label` button, which triggers the `:new` action in `ShippingLabelsController`, which prefills the form and triggers the `:perform` action of delayed job for creating the label. And the error happens after the job starts.

Comment: where do you call "find_order"? you can add a begin/rescue statement around that call to catch the ResourceNotFound excaption

Comment: "How do I notify a user" - how does a user get to this method in the first place?

Comment: User tries to create a shipping label for order and gets into this method under hood

Comment: Well then, just as arieljuod says, you can rescue in your shipping labels controller. With `rescue_from` on controller level, for example. Or `begin/rescue` in the action body.

Comment: where's that `perform` method being called? you need to provide the context of the request that triggers that code, it's impossible to suggest anything if you don't explian the complete flow "user tries to create a shipping label" is not clear, what controller/action/code is triggered by that action of the user?

Comment: Please see the edit, I updated the question

Comment: I don't see a Controller in your stack. Is this called from ActiveJob?

Comment: @Schwern, it is called before job

Comment: @Dende Let me see if I understand. You're asking how to get an error in a delayed job back to the user?

Comment: @3limin4t0r, in the `ShippingLabelsController`, which prefills the shipping label form and then triggers the job to create the label

Comment: @Dende Could you show us how the job is called in the Controller? Is it `perform_now` or `perform_later`?

Comment: @Schwern, the error happens in one of models, after the job starts. I want to notify the user that the job will not fullfill due to the error

Comment: @Schwern, `perform_later`

Answer (score 0):

`SomeJob.perform_later` fires off an asynchronous job. We can't know when it will complete. So yes, this is tricky to inform the user there was an error. But does the user need to be informed?

The nice thing about queued jobs is if they fail you can try them again. And again. And again until they work or you give up. When you're working with APIs there will be temporary errors with the API and network that will resolve themselves. Don't bother the user with these.

[ActiveJob has `retry_on`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActiveJob/Exceptions/ClassMethods.html) to tell a job what exceptions to retry.

```
class SomeJob < ApplicationJob
  retry_on ActiveResource::ResourceNotFound

  ...
end
```

Now your job will quietly retry if there is an API failure.

`ActiveResource::ResourceNotFound` is a rather coarse exception that could happen for many reasons, so you'll eventually want to catch and rethrow more specific exceptions in your model to fine tune your error handling.

---

Retries have a limit. If the number of retries are exhausted then a human needs to get involved and see what's wrong. That human is not the user, they don't know how to fix it, it is the administrator.

When `retry_on` exhausts its attempts the exception will bubble up to the underlying queuing system which should then inform the administrator that there's a dead item in the queue. The details of this depends on what queuing system you're using.

---

If the user does need to be informed, there's several options. One is to add an array of errors to the User model. The UI would pop off and display any errors in the User's error array, possibly in a flash.

Then you pass the User into the job. If the job has any errors they are caught and added to its associated User's error array. The next time that user uses your UI they will see the errors.

Comment: Or, if the user _needs_ to be informed, the job can send an email or something.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I've put in a sketch of how you can queue up errors for the user and display them later.

Comment: Or something like that, yes. Email has the advantage of not needing user to sign in. May be useful if the process is important. Of course, if one is feeling fancy, they can create a full-blown notification subsystem out of this. With emailable and non-emailable notification types, etc.

Comment: Damn, my hands are getting all itchy just thinking about this. Good software design exercise. :)

Comment: This error happens because the order, which user tries to access, cannot be accessed due to access token expiration. So, I know that it happens and I and user will not be able to do anything about it. I want to let a user know about the error that they should stop trying to access the order.